# texture swapping in 2d

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm new with dx programming and I have a problem with textures.
I'm doing a 2d engine, I implemented a simple sprite batching, I can write on my dynamic buffer, set uv coordinates and draw some sprites on the screen.
Everything works fine if I'm using a single texture but, when I want to change texture and draw new sprites nothing works anymore.
What I'm doing is loading the textures using the function D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile and storing the pointer.
Then in the rendering loop, when I'm done with one texture, I use:
PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture_pointer)
to swap to another texture but this last function crashes, it works only with one single texture.
What am I supposed to do to swap from a texture to another texture?
Thank you!

Comment: That sounds correct in theiry so it's likely your implementation is broken but we'd need to see some code to see what is wrong.